# Will using a regex that ends in '$' do an optimized backwards search

Tags: python, regex

I have a string variable that is a huge HTML document. It contains 80,000+ characters.

I am trying to efficiently test whether or not it is a complete HTML document or not. I have defined "complete" as a document which ends with `</html>` and may have whitespace (e.g. new lines) at the very end.

I originally wrote this code:

```
if re.search(r'</html>\s*$', content):
    # complete HTML
```

By a co-worker of mine commented on it, saying that the matching logic of that regex may not do a backwards search through the string to be most efficient. He suggested using this code instead:

```
if content.rstrip().endswith('</html>'):
    # complete HTML
```

We do need to optimize because this code is run very frequently.

Will the regex code do a backwards search through the string because it includes the `$` character?

Comment: Would a parser like BeautifulSoup be able to solve this problem? Rolling your own regex is rarely the easiest way to parse HTML.

Comment: We are already using BeautifulSoup4 with the lxml parser but it does not fail parsing the document if it is incomplete HTML, it just adds the missing closing tags. This code is being added before the BS4 parsing to check if it is a complete document or not so we can handle it specially. If there is someway to utilize our bs object to check if it is a complete document or not, that would suffice, but I couldn't find anyway to do that.

Comment: So, by that definition, `"</html>"` alone would be a "valid" HTML document? That seems a bit weak, and should highlight the notion that you really should use an HTML parser instead of a regular expression for this...

Comment: For our purpose in this `if` block, yes `"</html>"` can be considered a complete document. I am not sure why you used the word "valid" in a quoted context, I didn't use that word in my question. This code is not for determining the validity of the HTML, just whether or not we received the expected end of an HTML document in a response.

Comment: I think your coworker's idea is reasonable although it may be reasonable to lowercase it to catch `</HTML>`. You could trim it down to the last bit of the text and just do a compare: `content[-48:].strip()[-7:].lower() == '</html>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the regex engine will be looking for the longest leftmost match.  It can probably optimize for finding the static string `</html>` fairly quickly; the longer a piece of static string you can provide it for anchoring, the faster it will run.  But I concur with your colleague's advice.

Comment: I agree with your agreement. As a general rule of thumb, there's at the very least some overhead with using regex, and at worst unknown/unoptimized behavior going on under the hood. Because of this, if you can do a simple string operation instead of using a regexp, that's almost always the better option.